# PayPal Adaptive Chained Payments reverse immediately with the information "Your Payment can't be completed.Please return to ... and try again"

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained-payments

My Marketplace has been doing well until 2 days ago. I'm using PayPal chained Adaptive there were 15 Sellers where customers were able to complete the transaction successfully for 10 among 15 sellers. Rest 5 sellers were having an issue. Customer is not able to complete it instead it getting reversed immediately with the information on top of PayPal Screen "Your payment can't be completed. Please return to the participating website and try again".

I'm quite confused why it is behaving like this for few sellers but for rest of them is absolutely working fine. I've tried to contact PayPal support but haven't recieved a single response.

Hereby I have collected IPN trace logs of reversed transaction. Please see below. I replaced Sensitive info with `**`. Looking forward & excited to know about the cause of the issue, that would be of great help.

IPN Trace:

https://codeshare.io/Maybi

Comment: Please format this appropriately.

Comment: Thanks @SatejS  i have modified appropriately

Comment: @jahir, can you give the support number?